# How make several .load() on one page for IE 11?

Tags: jquery

I have several div for content. In first div i load content from video.html, in two div i load content from games.html, in three div i load content from news.html and etc.
In FF, Chrome, Opera, Webkit all ok, but in IE 11 not work.
How make several .load() on one page for IE 11 or how make warning popup for only IE 11?

```
$(".islice").load("home.html?" + new Date().getTime() );
```

not work.

My code:

```
$('a#ht_nws div:eq(0)').load('../news.html #cntntblck:eq(1) a:eq(0)');
$('a#ht_nws font:eq(0)').load('../news.html #cntntblck:eq(1) h3');
$('a#ht_nws div:eq(1)').load('../news.html #cntntblck:eq(2) a:eq(0)');
$('a#ht_nws font:eq(1)').load('../news.html #cntntblck:eq(2) h3');
$('a#ht_nws div:eq(2)').load('../news.html #cntntblck:eq(3) img:eq(0)');
$('a#ht_nws font:eq(2)').load('../news.html #cntntblck:eq(3) h3');
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: This looks like a very inefficient way to do it, since you're calling the same page each time. Call it once, put the parsed HTML into a variable, and then use jQuery functions to put the appropriate parts into each DIV.

Comment: Barmar- Ok. Thanks. I test it after 2- 3 hours. I write about results later, sorry my delay.

Comment: Barmar- "This looks like a very inefficient way to do it, since you're calling the same page each time."     
It also does not work:
  $('a#ht_nws div:eq(0)').load('../news.html #cntntblck:eq(1) a:eq(0)');
  $('a#ht_vds div:eq(0)').load('../video.html #cntntblck:eq(1) div');
  $('a#ht_wbcms div:eq(0)').load('../camsw.html #cntntblck:eq(1) div:eq(0)');
  $('a#ht_gms div:eq(0)').load('../games.html #cntntblck:eq(1) div');

Answer (score 1):

After viewing the comments, I made a solution for you.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "news.html",
    dataType: 'html',
    cache: false
}).done(function(html) {
    var readyHTML = $("<div>" + html + "</div>");
    $('a#ht_nws div:eq(0)').html($(readyHTML).find("#cntntblck:eq(1) a:eq(0)")[0].outerHTML);
    $('a#ht_nws font:eq(0)').html($(readyHTML).find("#cntntblck:eq(1) h3")[0].outerHTML);
    //rest of the queries
});
```

The code simply loads `news.html` via `$.ajax()` function and put the whole HTML wrapped in a `<div>` in `readyHTML`, because `$.find()` cannot search for the 1st layer in an HTML file. Then through multiple lines, change the HTML content to those in the `readyHTML`.

`.outerHTML` is a native function, which require us to strip down the jQuery objects to work, hence getting the `[0]` position from the jQuery elements.

Comment: Thank Daniel, i not have "Ajax library". For this need a install "Ajax" plugin?

Comment: @Tuchkovo-Auto.RuSorrymyEng. It's in jQuery, you can use this.

Comment: @Tuchkovo-Auto.RuSorrymyEng. Did it have any error messages? Because I've tested it myself with the latest jquery.

Comment: @Tuchkovo-Auto.RuSorrymyEng. Also, ajax will not work with Chrome locally, that means not on a server, because of security reasons. Please test on a server.

Comment: @ Daniel Cheung. "ajax will not work with Chrome locally, that means not on a server, because of security reasons."- i know it. I use FireFox & jQuery-2.1.0. I not use ajax. My code is work on FF, Chrm, Wbkt, only IE not work.

Comment: @Tuchkovo-Auto.RuSorrymyEng. `$.load()` is also an ajax function. Please check again and give more information if you want your problem solved. If it is already solved, please post your answer.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Sorry. $.ajax({url: "news.html", ... code ...}); plus $.ajax({url: "video.html", ... code ...}); not work on IE 11. Sorry.